# Cocoa API implementation for Linux?

Tags: linux, osx, wine, api

Is there any Wine-like project for running OS X apps on Linux? I mean an implementation of Cocoa API for standard Linux machine, as it is done with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

There's CocoTron under an MIT license, but I can't tell if it is still alive or not. https://github.com/cjwl/cocotron . Has code checked in from 6 months ago but don't see much on the net about it.